# What does the "Survival Chance" in "Why you got fired" represent?

Tags: dont-get-fired

In Don't Get Fired, every time you get fired for one reason or another, your survival chance for that reason increased by 10% until a certain point.  "Failing the Interview" is capped at 90% for me, but I have hit 100% for "Because there's no more work to do."  When survival chance is at 100% for a specific reason, will I never get fired for this reason again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As survival chance increases the chance of getting fired for that reason decreases. If your survival chance for something is at 100% you won't get fired for that same reason again.

Answer (score 0):

Each "Ways to get fired" has a maximum "Survival chance", the "Failing the interview" starts at 0% and caps at 90%, some ways to get fired caps at 90%, some caps at 99%, some at 99,9%, and some of them even at 100%. Most of them caps at 99,9%